# Displaying images downloaded from Firebase in a GridView on a Fragment keeps crashing upon opening fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, gridview, baseadapter

I am creating a gallery for our android app using a GridView on one of our fragments which are located in a navigation drawer. I created a custom adapter for the image view that uses Picasso to display the images in a Image View. I made a method called DohvatiSlike() that downloads images from firebase and saves them in a File variable. When i build the app and run it, whenever i open the gallery from the navigation drawer it crashes the app. If i exclude the line setting the GalleryGridAdapter in the onCreateView there is no crash but it obviously doesn't work. Can anyone help me find the problem?

This is the GalleryFragment code:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationItem {
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<File> slike;
private int position;
GridView galleryGridView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_fragment, container, false);
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    galleryGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gallery_gridview);
    DohvatiSlike();
    galleryGridView.setAdapter(new GalleryGridAdapter(getActivity(), slike));

    return v;
}

public void DohvatiSlike(){
    mDatabaseRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images");
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                File slika = postSnapshot.getValue(File.class);
                slike.add(slika);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText((AppCompatActivity)getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

This is the Adapter code:

```
public class GalleryGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
public List<File> slike;

public GalleryGridAdapter(Context context, List<File> slikice){
    slike = slikice;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slike.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return slike.indexOf(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(500, 500));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(slike.indexOf(position)).into(imageView);
        return imageView;
}
```

}

EDIT*

Here is the crash log

```
 Process: hr.foi.air1817.botanico, PID: 26065
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at hr.foi.air1817.botanico.adapters.GalleryGridAdapter.getCount(GalleryGridAdapter.java:26)
    at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:211)
    at hr.foi.air1817.botanico.fragments.GalleryFragment$1.onDataChange(GalleryFragment.java:62)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have been at this for two days straight and just can't get it to work, and advice or ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem with asynchronous operations, your code will always crash because you are setting the adapter data before it's reached from Firebase, when you do this

```
DohvatiSlike();
    galleryGridView.setAdapter(new GalleryGridAdapter(getActivity(), slike));
```

the method  `DohvatiSlike();` is still requesting the data and may not finish adding the elements at the slike `Array` you have.

Instead, move the setting of the adapter inside your  `DohvatiSlike();` method

```
     public void DohvatiSlike(){

           slike = new List<>();                


  mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images");
                mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            File slika = postSnapshot.getValue(File.class);
                            slike.add(slika);
                        }

                    galleryGridView.setAdapter(new GalleryGridAdapter(getActivity(), slike));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText((AppCompatActivity)getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    });
            }
```

When you execute `DohvatiSlike()` you will need to wait depending on your internet connection to fetch that data, after that data is fetched you fill your Array, in this case you are requesting the data and immediately setting the adapter with data that might not been fetched yet, instead just set the adapter after all the data has been parsed and added inside your `onDataChange`.

Also, when showing views do it inside `onViewCreated()` because `onCreateView()` is just for inflating your view elements

Comment: Thank you for your advice, what you say makes sense and I did as you instructed however the app still crashes upon being opened for one second longer. Something else might still be causing an issue, this is my first time creating an android app so it's highly likely.

Comment: can you detail what the crashlogs says ? What I answer is the method you should use to load the data into your adaper, otherwise it will crash everytime you start the fragment

Comment: you are getting the error because you are passing a file into picasso Picasso.with(mContext).load(slike.indexOf(position)).into(imageView); , you should pass a url there not a File

Comment: I have edited the post to include a crash log, i will also look in to getting the url for the images

Comment: edited my answer, make sure to initialize your array inside your Dohvatslike() method, either way it will be null